# How to live stream mongodb data to front end with nodejs/mongodb/socketio?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, socket.io, passport.js

I am trying to build a live dashboard that streams data from a mongodb capped collection to the front end of whichever user is logged in. The backend will be python or similar and will update user collections with new data continuously. I am using passportjs for authentication, and passport-socketio-redis to integrate socketio.

The first goal I believe is to add the username as a value to the socketio client list.

Example: one client connected, client list is: [ 'wukBbRD3vcXCuqylAAAA' ].

Add user value, now the client list looks like: [ { 'wukBbRD3vcXCuqylAAAA' : username } ]

After this I would loop through the client list periodically (every 1 second or so) and start a mongodb stream for each client. Then I would stream the resulting data to that client using their socket ID. (I am assuming that upon disconnect, the client key:val pair will be removed, may have to add additional code to kill the mongodb stream.)

**I have come up with the code below, it will not do the above correctly, as I'm currently stuck trying to figure out how to pair the username with the socketio client id.**

**Is this even a good approach for building a live dashboard? The more I get into this, the less it seems plausible/scalable. Thanks all for your help!**

**/bin/www**

```
var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('project:server');
var http = require('http');

//misc server initialization stuff left out to save space. this file calls in sockets.js below

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
require('../sockets')(io);
```

**sockets.js**

```
var passport = require('passport');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var redis = require('redis').createClient();
var session = require('express-session');
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
var socketioRedis = require("passport-socketio-redis");
var History = require('./models/history');

var clientinfo;
var user_name;

module.exports = function (io) { 

  io.use(socketioRedis.authorize({
  passport:passport,
  cookieParser: cookieParser,
  key:         'express.sid',       
  secret:      'keyboard cat',    
  store:       new RedisStore({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379, client: redis }),
  success:     authorizeSuccess,  //callback on success
  fail:        authorizeFail     //callback on fail/error 
  }));

function authorizeSuccess(data, accept){
    //get the username
    user_name = data.user.id;
    accept();
}

function authorizeFail(data, message, error, accept)
{
    if(error)
        accept(new Error(message));
}

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  //get list of clients - I believe I need to somehow add the username to the client list here.
  clientinfo = Object.keys(io.engine.clients)
});


setInterval(function(){
  for (key in clientdict) {
    //start new stream for each client (not 100% sure multiple streams can exist)
    streamData (key, clientdict[key])
  }
}
},1000);

//create mongodb stream and emit to client
function streamData (u_id, sockvar) {
    var stream = History.find({ user_id: u_id}, {'_id':0, 'test':1}).tailable(true).stream();
      stream.on('data', function (doc) {
        io.to(sockvar).emit('dash_data', { dash_data: doc });
    });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May have solved this - should have read the documentation better. Turns out passport-socketio-redis allows you to access a 'socket.request.user' which returns the information about the user. See the code below for creation and deletion of key:value pairs upon new connections/disconnects

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  clientdict[socket.request.user.id] = socket.id;
  //console.log(socket.request.user)
  //all clients console.log(Object.keys(io.engine.clients))
  console.log(clientdict)
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    delete clientdict[socket.request.user.id]
    console.log('removed')
    console.log(socket.request.user.id)
  });
});
```